# web push notification on mozilla

Tags: push-notification, mozilla, web-push

i am testing web push on my local.
below command gives me the push when i am capturing the end point on chrome.

```
curl --header "Authorization: key=XXXXXXXXXXXX" --header "Content-Type: application/json" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"fs...Tw:APA...SzXha\"]}"
```

but when i allow and capture end point on Mozilla.
response of above command:

```
{"multicast_id":############,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}
```

end point i recieve on mozilla
14:20:55.180 endpoint: `"https://updates.push.services.mozilla.com/wpush/v1/gAAAAABXobDz85y9Aqz5wn0PVS4ka-p7ESp8fviKNzDPQPWfR4kZfsgUZVx7MauSN4udurIBVlC8-LdG8hsC6jOchCNMEQ2vJ5pK9n-HVf2GpQm7PP6GrsfOjjIeP_uOJDOcMLD7GZKE"1 main.js:8:13`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple demo, which works in both browsers Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox: https://serviceworke.rs/push-simple_demo.html

Try to open it in both browsers and you will see which link you have to use to send a push message for your browser and a difference between links for Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox. For me, the links are:

Google Chrome

```
curl -H "TTL: 60" -X POST https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send/f3WCPreREPE:APA91bHqGD-Oc4o8LqxnuepBvw4SGtIlFeyxP0F2ksMjxPH9yZxLfGZx_6aN7X9cqiSvIQGN4HI6KnAiuWac-_jvKMb1vTFE7_GuPZG1WsNzhyEQVT-BdXIim79SJOyWbwkV91S23isP
```

Mozilla Firefox

```
curl -H "TTL: 60" -X POST https://updates.push.services.mozilla.com/wpush/v1/gAAAAABXt1OmbjxoPG6_YpmEzYZdsYWWE9bj_JQUUbqwuqTB53t_uBKW3bOZNqJ9BG0ZBkEOpPffYHUT3VW-iI7XeBtFydNWnx4KlIGKL75443jdErWhrarb9GAuzwdP_Cen0kOhDG3G
```

It also have the source code for client and server side.

Or look at the source code of java lib for WebPush notifications: https://github.com/MartijnDwars/web-push/blob/master/src/main/java/nl/martijndwars/webpush/PushService.java#L88-L115
The code is really easy and it explains how to build an HTTP request for FCM/GCM or Mozilla autopush.

Answer (score 0):

You must do a POST request to:

```
https://updates.push.services.mozilla.com/wpush/v1/gAAAAABXobDz85y9Aqz5wn0PVS4ka-p7ESp8fviKNzDPQPWfR4kZfsgUZVx7MauSN4udurIBVlC8-LdG8hsC6jOchCNMEQ2vJ5pK9n-HVf2GpQm7PP6GrsfOjjIeP_uOJDOcMLD7GZKE
```

You cannot use GCM for Mozilla. GCM is only for Chrome.

Comment: i agreed gcm is for chrome. what i am asking is when i run curl command using "v1/gAAAAABXobDz85y9Aqz5wn0PVS4ka-p7ESp8fviKNzDPQPWfR4kZfsgUZVx7MauSN4udurIBVlC8-LdG8hsC6jOchCNMEQ2vJ5pK9n-HVf2GpQm7PP6GrsfOjjIeP_uOJDOcMLD7GZKE" as my end point it says **InvalidRegistration**

Comment: As I said GCM says it is invalid because that registration belongs to Mozilla, not to GCM. BTW have you considered using a service like Pushpad to make things simpler?